# Python Arabic NLP

Tags: python, arabic, nlp

I'm in the process of assessing the capabilities of the NLTK in processing Arabic text in a research to analyze and extract sentiments.

Question is as follows:

1. Is the NTLK capable of handling and allows the analysis of Arabic text?
2. Is python capable of manipulating\tokenizing Arabic text?
3. Will I be able to parse and store Arabic text using Python?

If python and NTLK aren't the tools for this job, what tools would you recommend (if existent)?

Thank you.

---

#### EDIT

Based on research:

1. NTLK is only capable of stemming Arabic text: [Link](http://text-processing.com/demo/)
2. Python is capable of handling Arabic text since it supports UTF-8 unicode: [Link](http://www.spencegreen.com/2008/12/19/python-arabic-unicode/)
3. Parsing and Lemmatization of Arabic text can be done using: 
   SNLPG (The Stanford Natural Language Processing Group) Statistical Parser: [Link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple google search lead to these links:

[Arabic Natural Language Processing](https://sites.google.com/site/dyaafayedsite/)

[Using Python with the Quranic Arabic Corpus](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/comp-quran@comp.leeds.ac.uk/13493220.html)

[HOWTO: Working with Python, Unicode, and Arabic](http://www.spencegreen.com/2008/12/19/python-arabic-unicode/)

Are any of these useful?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However my question requires an answer based on experience in the topic above. I searched a lot and found many lexical parsers that are able to parse Arabic sentences based on the Penn Arabic Treebank but nothing regarding text analysis and sentiment extraction. I will keep this question unanswered for a while, maybe someone else can contribute some of his knowledge. If not I will consider yours as the correct answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You might consider editing your question to contain all the info you just provided in this comment.

Comment: @Bassem, I know this is an old post, however I'd like to know whether you have found a solution for extracting sentiments?

Comment: @Frumples I haven't found an off the shelf engine, we ended up building a proprietary solution which was never released.