# creating arabic corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, rapidminer

I'm doing the sentiment analysis for the Arabic language , I want to creat my own corpus , to do that , I collect 300 status from facebook and I classify them into positive and negative , now I want to do the tokenization of these status , in order to obain a list of words , and hen generate unigrams and bigrams, trigrams and use the cross fold validation , I'm using for the moment the nltk python, is this software able to do this task fr the arabic language or the rapis Minner will be better to work with , what do you think and I'm wondering how to generate the bigrams, trigrams and use the cross fold validation , is there any idea ??

Comment: If you use the right tokenizer, NLTK can handle Arabic. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035595/tokenization-of-arabic-words-using-nltk.

Comment: I have had better luck with MALLET. I agree with the comment above. The right tokenizer can handle Arabic. Once you have the text tokenized then the rest of the pipeline is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that rapidminer is very interesting and can handle this task. It contains several operators dealing with text mining. Also, it allows the creation of new operators with high fluency.