# NLP tools for right-to-left languages?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm trying to use NLP within a web application. What I wanna do is a little information extraction on Persian sentences. So I need some RTL-friendly NLP tools. I've tried python's [nltk](http://nltk.org) before but I don't know if it does support RTL languages as well. It's very good if it does because I have a good relationship with Django as well. Any information on this topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried using it for RTL, but I think it is perfectly capable of serving your needs, as it is a toolkit, not a system *per se*.
I could not find any restrictions regarding this. In fact, I have found some other references on people using it for Arabic:

1. [Tokenization of Arabic words using NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035595/tokenization-of-arabic-words-using-nltk)
2. [Python Arabic NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386856/python-arabic-nlp)

Now, you do need to find some Persian corpora. I could not find any during my brief research, but you can always hit the [NLTK Users Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nltk-users).